# chromewebdriver not launching

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

Chrome web driver isn't launching in my code.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\acer\Downloads\chromedriver-win64")
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

It gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\python_selenium\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\python_selenium\Test_case01\Login.py 
  File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\python_selenium\Test_case01\Login.py", line 2
    driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\acer\Downloads\chromedriver-win64")
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Change to following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\acer\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

The path is a normal string. Try using `driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\acer\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe")`

In a normal string python will escape with `\` but if you use `r` in front of the string will make it a raw string. The other option will be to escape the `\` symbol like this `\\`